# Send selectedText from AutocompleteTextView Automatically - Jquery / Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I searched a lot.
So I created an autocomplete jquery for **cityTextBox** and get the selectedItem from this autocomplete textbox. I split ***selectedItem*** with **"|"** and assign to **string[] lines** after user select it from autocomplete view. On my code I assign lines like below( lines[0] to cityTextBox and lines[1] to postCodeTextBox);

```js
 $('#postCodeTextBox').text = $("#<%=postCodeTextBox.ClientID%>").val(lines[1].trim());
                            $('#cityTextBox').text = $("#<%=cityTextBox.ClientID%>").val(lines[0].trim());
                        });
```

This all works fine after my select when I click to somewhere or focus ect(events that i define in **$("#cityTextBox").bind()**). this happens. But I just want to send the lines[0] and lines[1] to the text boxes automatically when I select from the autocomplete list without click etc. You can see my java script code below:

```js
$(function () {
        $("#cityTextBox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { cityName: $('#cityTextBox').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetCities",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    //error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //    alert(textStatus);
                    //}
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    var parameter = { selectedItem: ui.item.value }
                    function process() {
                        entered = $('#cityTextBox').val();
                        lines = entered.split("|");
                        $(function getLines () {
                            $('#postCodeTextBox').text = $("#<%=postCodeTextBox.ClientID%>").val(lines[1].trim());
                            $('#cityTextBox').text = $("#<%=cityTextBox.ClientID%>").val(lines[0].trim());
                        });
                    }                   
                }
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    //$("#cityTextBox").bind('mouseout', process);
                    $("#cityTextBox").bind('blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup errorscroll errorkeydown   ', process);
                    
                });
            },
            minLength: 3
        });
    });
```

I get the data from ESD table in database. And the query work properly. Here is the html code part :

```html
<table style="margin:50px; padding:10px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="countryLabel" runat="server" Text="Ülke : "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="countryDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="countryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="-1">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" >             
                    <asp:Label ID="postCodeLabel" runat="server" Text="Posta Kodu :"></asp:Label></td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="postCodeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="cityLabel" runat="server" Text="Şehir : "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cityTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```